# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ip' of undefined - express-rate-limit

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rate-limiting

Updated: because I understood that error is not related to my code.

Hi all!

I comment all of my code that related to express-rate-limit but this package still has an error.

My code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
// const RateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
const cors = require('cors')

// const apiLimiter = new RateLimit({
//     windowMs: 1000 * 60 * 5,
//     max: 5,
//     // message : "درخواست شما زیاد بوده لطفا 15 دقیقه دیگر دوباره تلاش کنید"
//     handler: function (req, res, /*next*/) {
//         res.json({
//             data: 'درخواست شما زیاد بوده لطفا 15 دقیقه دیگر دوباره تلاش کنید',
//             status: 'error'
//         })
//     }
// });

let prefixes = ["v1"];
for (let prefix of prefixes) {
    router.use(`/${prefix}/`, require(`./${prefix}/home`));
    router.use(`/${prefix}/auth`, cors(), require(`./${prefix}/auth`));
    router.use(`/${prefix}/admin`, cors(), require(`./${prefix}/admin`));

    // router.use(`/${prefix}/`, cors(), apiLimiter, require(`./${prefix}/home`));
    // router.use(`/${prefix}/auth`, cors(), apiLimiter, require(`./${prefix}/auth`));
    // router.use(`/${prefix}/admin`, cors(), apiLimiter, require(`./${prefix}/admin`));
}

module.exports = router;
```

The error text is:

```
C:\Users\Sayyid Ali Sajjadi D\Desktop\gheymat\node_modules\express-rate-limit\lib\express-rate-limit.js:16
      return req.ip;
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'ip' of undefined
    at Object.keyGenerator (C:\Users\Sayyid Ali Sajjadi D\Desktop\gheymat\node_modules\express-rate-limit\lib\express-rate-limit.js:16:18)
    at rateLimit (C:\Users\Sayyid Ali Sajjadi D\Desktop\gheymat\node_modules\express-rate-limit\lib\express-rate-limit.js:54:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sayyid Ali Sajjadi D\Desktop\gheymat\app\routes\index.js:20:39)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Application.setRouters (C:\Users\Sayyid Ali Sajjadi D\Desktop\gheymat\app\index.js:35:17)
    at new Application (C:\Users\Sayyid Ali Sajjadi D\Desktop\gheymat\app\index.js:13:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sayyid Ali Sajjadi D\Desktop\gheymat\server.js:4:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Plase help me! What should I do?

Comment: If you have commented out all code related to that module, and that module is still causing the error, you either didn't save your code or you didn't restart the server.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use it like this

```
router.use(`/${prefix}/`, cors(), apiLimiter, require(`./${prefix}/home`));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check typeof apiLimiter, you would get 'object'. You cannot call apiLimiter() unless typeof apiLimiter is a 'function'.

David's solution should do the trick